# Deleting rows in a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm trying to delete rows in a datagridview but its only deleting a select few from the bottom up of records that qualify. I need it to delete ALL the records. Please help! Here is my code:

```
For n As Int32 = DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        Dim c As Boolean
        c = DataGridView1.Rows(n).Cells(0).Value
        If c = True Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(n)
        Else
        End If
    Next n
```

Note: This code works on shorter lists but on larger lists it only deletes some of the selected records. By selected I mean records with the "c = True"

Comment: iterate backwards...think about what happens when you RemoveAt - everything move up one so some are skipped.  Also, removing DGV rows doesnt nothing to the data if it is still bound to a DataTable.

Comment: @Plutonix isn't that what I am already doing??? If so, why isn't it working?

Comment: @LarsTech I thought so too

Comment: Sorry, eyes have been acting up all day.  Still "delete ALL the records" wont happen from fiddling with the control

Comment: This is a debugging problem.  The only thing we can guess is that the cell isn't always true when you think it's true.

Comment: @LarsTech The cell in question is a checkbox column, not sure if that helps.

Comment: Turning on Option Strict surely wont hurt

Comment: @Plutonix Turning on Option Strict did not fix the issue.

Comment: Put the records in a separate list then go through the list and remove the records from the datagridview...

Comment: @Plutonix I still have not solved this issue, do you have any further advice?

Answer (score -1):

I would iterate top to bottom so that you don't possibly skip rows as you delete them.

```
For each row as DataRow in DataGridView1.Rows
    Dim c As Boolean
    c = isNumeric(row(0)
    If c = True Then
        DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row)
    Else
    End If
Next
```

This Code should work for what you were wanting.

Comment: Are you aware that iterating and removing datarows at the same time will cause you an error?

Comment: No I wasn't I have never had to do this, but just thought this could work.